# How to change the icon of toggle navigation link in magento2

Tags: magento2, frontend, image, static-content

[image]

Please check the screen shot I want to make close button on toggle navigation link.

Comment: did you tried this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/193962/54588

Comment: not working sir

Comment: are you using luma theme ?

Comment: yes sir i am using luma theme

Comment: Then it should work , I posted after testing . any error? share your web URL

Comment: this is my site url just for test http://apetrailportfolio.com/mage

Comment: your site is distorted , please rectify and let me know

Comment: css changes are not reflecting , did you followed all steps ...

Comment: yes sir i follow all step

Comment: http://apetrailportfolio.com/mod/ sir check update url

Comment: still css is not reflecting , in which file you updated it ? and did you run all the commands

Comment: mod/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/web/css/source/_extends.less

Comment: wrong place , you are going totally wrong , do not make changes in any file inside vendor..... first extend your theme

Comment: you mean to say that in i do change in add/frontend theme

Comment: yes your theme should inside /app/design/frontend/

Comment: ok let me check i update

Comment: what is your custom theme extended path ?

Comment: public_html/mod/app/design/frontend/Sports/Demo/web/css/source

Comment: check my url sir

Comment: No still there is correction  .. see this should your path /app/design/frontend/Sports/demo/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less

Comment: yes sir i have update it as above path

Comment: now follow all the steps and run commands

Comment: I hope it should work now