# how to put close button on hamburger menu click while it is expended

Tags: magento2, menu

How to put the close button on `hamburger menu` while it is **expended** ?

Comment: change icon content value

Comment: which file in change icon its job matter sir please tell me

Comment: did you get the solution

Comment: not  sir you cannot repy me right answer which i do change

Comment: try the solution I provided , and you will set close icon on expand

Comment: let me know if any problem

Comment: @Monukumar I have created custom theme inherit from blank theme, in my mobile view menu not visible under hamburger menu instead showing showing header panel, alignment looking bad, how to move menu into hamburger in the mobile view My post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328503/57334

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change css of icon. Create file in your custom theme

```
app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/web/css/source/_navigation.less
```

You can refer to this file, under *Mobile* section

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_navigation.less
```

Comment: I was referring to magento 2. pls reply with correct path of file.

Comment: @Monukumar I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

To change the menu icon **from bar to close iocn** when expanded follow below steps:

create `_extend.less` at below location with same directory structure if not exists

```
/app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

Now add below css for changing bar icons to close icon

```
.nav-open .nav-toggle::before {
    content: '\e616';
}
```

Here in `_extend.less` , you can place all your custom CSS or LESS style rules.

After that run following commands if you are in developer mode while keeping cache disabled:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

In production mode , also run below command with above commands to take effect.

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

**Note:** Tested on LUMA theme

Comment: Why do you need to set the mode to production?

Comment: if not using grunt then need run commands specified for developer mode and production mode. no need to switch mode.. you can run in whatever mode you are

Comment: Do I need to add the `_extend.less` anywhere? I can't get it to reflect... The code it self is actually working in inspection mode.

Comment: place extend.less in your custom theme as above mentioned path and add css there. then run commands whichever are required in your case

Comment: See, I did do so... It's not reflecting it...  How would I debug that? Can I check if the css was added to any files? What can  I do?

Comment: inspect and check your added css in your extend.less/compiled css

Comment: Nothing in styles-m.css... Should it be double ::? also, the -> ' <- is missing in the content:

Comment: kindly post your extended theme path,  so I can see how you are extending your theme.

Comment: I got it ;) It was the missing ` ' ` in the content property :p You should edit your answer and fix this :D Thank you very much for your interest. I already up-voted your answer!