# Hamburger menu | How to change the icon to X when expanded

Tags: magento2, css, hamburger-menu

I found this which was quiet helpful:

[how to put close button on hamburger menu click while it is expended](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193924/how-to-put-close-button-on-hamburger-menu-click-while-it-is-expended/193962#193962)

Adding CSS: '\e616' to the `.nav-toggle:before` class changed the button to X. however, I want to keep the 3 lines when the menu is closed and only to display the X when it's expanded.

I tired adding the property to `.nav-toggle:after` but that didn't work.

**How can I change the icon of the hamburger menu to "X" when it's expanded on mobile?**

Menu Closed:

[image]

Menu opened:

[image]

*Magento 2.1.8 and custom theme*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below css for add **"X"** icon when hamburger expanded on mobile.

`.nav-open .nav-toggle::before {
    content: '\e616';
}`

Comment: on `.nav-open`... how could I missed that :D

Comment: happen in sometimes :)